# Do the Voyager probes experience time moving faster due to relativity?

Tags: voyager, time, spacetime

Time goes faster the weaker the gravitational field you are in as long as your velocity is constant. The Voyager probes have moved a long way from the sun and its planets so I presume time must be going slowly faster for them. Is this true and if so do we know how much faster time is going for them than Earth?

Comment: "slowly faster"?

Answer (score 4):

You can see [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/6008/265) for the formulae. We would expect that Voyager 1's local time is faster than Earth time by about one part in one hundred million.

I don't think that the Voyager oscillator is stable enough to measure that small of a difference. So we can't directly answer "is this true". However it would be a mind-blowing discovery throwing our most basic understanding of physics into disarray if it *weren't* true.